# CMake - Using POSIX feature test macros?

Tags: c, cmake, posix, language-features

CMake as a set of handy properties that correspond to setting certain feature test macros in the underlying compiler.  For example, with `gcc`:

```
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

will result in the following flags being passed:

```
-std=c11 -Wpedantic
```

which will also set the feature test macros

```
_ISOC11_SOURCE
```

This works quite well as I can rely on CMake to deal with the differences between compilers. I was looking through [the list of feature test macros](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_gbl/CMAKE_C_KNOWN_FEATURES.html#prop_gbl:CMAKE_C_KNOWN_FEATURES) that CMakes supports, however, and I couldn't locate any related to the `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` feature test. Is there any better way to do this other than `add_definitions(-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L)`?

Comment: I'd like this too. I suspect CMake doesn't provide it because POSIX is not available at all on some platforms supported by CMake.

Comment: Shouldn't CMake simply not define _POSIX_C_SOURCE on those platforms that don't support it?